# How to update vaiables in tensorflow scan

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to make a variable in tensorflow, and then update it in tf.scan. First I tried something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    tf.get_variable('bar', initializer=tf.zeros([1.0]))

def repeat_me(last, current):
    with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=True):
        bar = tf.get_variable('bar')
        bar.assign_add(tf.constant([1.0]))
    return bar
output = tf.scan(repeat_me, tf.range(5), initializer=tf.constant([1.0]))

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    out = sess.run(output)
    print(out)
    with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=True):
        print(tf.get_variable('bar').eval())
```

This does not seem to update the variable with the name of 'bar'.

```
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
[ 0.]
```

What is strange to me is the following modification of the "repeat_me" function changes the behavior.

```
def repeat_me(last, current):
    with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=True):
        bar = tf.get_variable('bar')
        b = bar.assign_add(tf.constant([1.0]))
    return b
```

Then, the script spits out this:

```
[[ 5.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 5.]]
[ 5.]
```

Could anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) says:

> Returns:
>
> Same as "ref". Returned as a convenience for operations that want to use the new value after the variable has been updated.

`bar.assign_add(tf.constant([1.0]))` returns an operation, and you need to catch it so that the scan function can make use of it. In your first version, the operation isn't saved or returned, so what you get from `repeat_me` is still the original bar.

In other words, this will also work:

```
with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=True):
    bar = tf.get_variable('bar')
    return bar.assign_add(tf.constant([1.0]))
```